# OpenGL ES / Vulkan: Per fragment stencil write/test (on Qualcomm Snapdragon XR2)

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, vulkan, fragment-shader, stencil-buffer

I would like to render two meshes, the first one writing into the stencil buffer and the second one testing against it.
I want to do that on a per fragment level though (the fragment shader of the first object should define which value to write into the stencil buffer and the fragment shader of the second object should define whether and against which stencil value the fragments of the second object should be clipped).

My Target Platform is the Oculus Quest 2, which has a Qualcomm Snapdragon XR.

If the platform would support GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil, I could use that, but that's only supported on some Mali GPUs.

The reason I want to use stencils is that I want to render everything in a single forward rendering pass for performance reasons and since I'm already forced to use fragment discard in my shaders, early z-rejection is off the table anyway so that's not a concern.

How can I achieve per fragment stencil writing/testing on Qualcomm Snapdragon XR2 in either OpenGL ES 3.0 or Vulkan?

any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem here is, hence probably why this question does not attract answers. You might want to reword the question to make it more clear what are you trying to do, and what problems you have encountered in achieving that. Seems to me you are describing pretty basic stencil operation setup, which should simply work. What do you mean by "per fragment"? As opposed to what? Stencil buffer and render passes **are** per framgent entities.

Comment: @krOoze maybe I didn't word it well indeed. What I mean by 'per fragment' is that I can control in the fragment shader which stencil value to output and which stencil value to clip against.

Comment: Did not help. What do you mean by "which stencil value". There's only one stencil value.

Comment: Per-chance do you mean the reference?

Answer (score 1):

I had to print out all available extensions on the Quest 2 recently for a project and can confirm that `GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil` *is* supported.

To be clear though, this extension only enables *reading* the stencil value, *not* writing to it.

If it helps, these are the supported extensions:

````
GL_OES_EGL_image_external
GL_OES_EGL_sync
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_framebuffer_object
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr
GL_OES_texture_compression_astc
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_read_format_bgra
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float
GL_QCOM_alpha_test
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map
GL_EXT_sRGB
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
GL_EXT_texture_format_sRGB_override
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_EXT_copy_image
GL_EXT_geometry_shader
GL_EXT_tessellation_shader
GL_OES_texture_stencil8
GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks
GL_OES_shader_image_atomic
GL_OES_sample_variables
GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp
GL_EXT_EGL_image_external_wrap_modes
GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture
GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2
GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation
GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array
GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
GL_EXT_gpu_shader5
GL_EXT_robustness
GL_EXT_texture_buffer
GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch
GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil
GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array
GL_OES_sample_shading
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_EXT_debug_label
GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a
GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_vertex_array_object
GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
GL_KHR_debug
GL_EXT_YUV_target
GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control
GL_EXT_texture_norm16
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_OES_surfaceless_context
GL_OVR_multiview
GL_OVR_multiview2
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8
GL_KHR_no_error
GL_EXT_debug_marker
GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3
GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture
GL_EXT_buffer_storage
GL_EXT_external_buffer
GL_EXT_blit_framebuffer_params
GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance
GL_EXT_protected_textures
GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers
GL_QCOM_texture_foveated
GL_QCOM_texture_foveated2
GL_QCOM_texture_foveated_subsampled_layout
GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_noncoherent
GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_rate
GL_EXT_memory_object
GL_EXT_memory_object_fd
GL_EXT_EGL_image_array
GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation
GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior
GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage
GL_EXT_blend_func_extended
GL_EXT_clip_control
GL_OES_texture_view
GL_EXT_fragment_invocation_density
GL_QCOM_motion_estimation
GL_QCOM_validate_shader_binary
GL_QCOM_YUV_texture_gather
GL_IMG_texture_filter_cubic```
````

Comment: hi, could you tell me how to extract all the support GLES EXTENSIONS. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can have per-invocation stencil reference values with `VK_EXT_shader_stencil_export`. Nevertheless that extension is not widely supported.

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems you will need to find another way.